# Loop of a list in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, sum

I want to define a function, short_pnl which takes two parameters:

- positions (list) of strike prices for each future contract
- mtm (list) of the current market value of each asset
  To simplify the exercise, I will assume that positions and mtm lists have the same length and that the order is identical (first element in positions can be compared to the first element in mtm, etc.). I will also assume that all the futures in the portfolio are not yet up to maturity.

This function should compute and return the P&L (net income) of the portfolio.

Example:

I hold a porfolio of 3 future contracts on 3 different underlying assets:

Future A (SHORT) with a strike price of 100
Future B (SHORT) with a strike price of 140
Future C (SHORT) with a strike price of 200
Tonight, the market closes and the following market prices are spotted:

A closes at 110
B closes at 120
C closes at 180
The P&L portfolio can be computed like this: (100 - 110) + (140 - 120) + (200 - 180) = 30

My question is, how can i do this? I tried to write a piece of code in python but doesn't seem to work

```
positions=[100, 140, 200]
mtm=[110, 120, 180]
for i in range(0,3):
    short_pnl=positions[i]-mtm[i]
    print(short_pnl)
```

Furthermor, I have to make true this test:

import unittest
from financials import forward_price, short_pnl

```
class TestFinancials(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_forward_price_no_interest_rate(self):
        self.assertEqual(forward_price(100, 0, 1), 100)
        self.assertEqual(forward_price(100, 0, 2), 100)
        self.assertEqual(forward_price(100, 0, 3), 100)
        self.assertEqual(forward_price(100, 0, 4), 100)
        self.assertEqual(forward_price(100, 0, 5), 100)
```

Thank you!

Comment: I guess += instead of = on line 4 should work

Comment: plus you have syntax error in ```short_pnl=positions[i])-(mtm[i])```, it should be ```short_pnl=positions[i]-(mtm[i])```, also you can remove the parantheses from mtm

Comment: 1. Init short_pnl = 0 before loop, 2), 2. Don't hardcode 3, use `for i in range(len(positions))`, and 3) use `short_pnl+=positions[i]-(mtm[i])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using coding changes in comments we have:

```
positions=[100, 140, 200]
mtm=[110, 120, 180]
short_pnl = 0
for i in range(len(positions)):
    short_pnl+=positions[i]-(mtm[i])
    print(short_pnl)
```

But, this can written more preferably using zip as:

```
short_pnl = 0
for p, m in zip(positions, mtm):
    short_pnl += p - m
    print(short_pnl)
```

Or if all you care about is the final result use:

```
print(sum(p-m for p, m in zip(positions, mtm)))  # Output: 30
```

Comment: I have to make True this test: 
import unittest
from financials import forward_price, short_pnl

class TestFinancials(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_forward_price_no_interest_rate(self):
        self.assertEqual(forward_price(100, 0, 1), 100)
        self.assertEqual(forward_price(100, 0, 2), 100)
        self.assertEqual(forward_price(100, 0, 3), 100)
        self.assertEqual(forward_price(100, 0, 4), 100)
        self.assertEqual(forward_price(100, 0, 5), 100)

Comment: @FrankPlatania--This seem like a different question. Also, you don't provide any information on the function `forward_price`.  What are the arguments? Is the function suppose to implement [Forward Price Definition](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/f/forwardprice.asp#:~:text=Forward%20price%20is%20the%20predetermined,predetermined%20date%20in%20the%20future.)